# Where is the implementation part of frameworks' header files (objective-C)?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, header

I am learning Objective-C, but can't understand one thing with the frameworks. Each framework in objective-C contains header files which contain only @interface part. That means that header files only declare difference methods and do not implement them. Is this implementation part hidden in the frameworks or something, because I can't get how it works.

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: The implementation files are already compiled, if it isn't an open source framework you cannot get the code.

Comment: so there is no way to edit them for instance?

Comment: @user2759428 No, you cannot edit them (unless the source code was provided). You can extend them by [adding a category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW1), but if you don't have the source code, you cannot edit them (nor even see the implementation).

Answer (score 0):

> Is this implementation part hidden in the frameworks or something

Well, sort of. It's compiled (the actual source code is **not** present neither in the SDK nor in the OS) and only the binary executable code is contained within the dynamic library that resides inside the framework.

It is still possible to use them (i. e. link against them), obviously (see this for an explanation), but you cannot edit the source code. In theory, you could try binpatching them (i. e. disassembling, analyzing and editing the executable file using a hex editor or something), but that's neither recommended (you can screw up your entire system if you do one slight thing wrong), nor easy.